# Vuejs pwa service worker is not working offline with Heroku

Tags: vue.js, heroku, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have made a site with vuejs and it has pwa support; hence it should work offline. I host the site on heroku. I confirm that it was good, but some days ago it stopped working offline, appearently with no reason. If I try serving it with a local server, the offline pwa works. But with heroku it does not work, the console logs `service worker registered` and also`service worker cached`, but if I turn on the airplane mode it does not show the cached site but the usual dyno game.

This is the link to the code: https://github.com/euberdeveloper/unitn-tronchet

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL of your Heroku app? Service Workers work on either localhost, or on a HTTPS domain, and the caching of the files are specific to a single sub domain. Heroku would most probably always be in HTTPS, so maybe the subdomain has changed and therefore considered a new site visit everytime?

Comment: If you see the readme of the repo, you can read that the URL is https://unitn-tronchet.herokuapp.com. So it Is https. The problem is that it used to work, so it is possible to make it working on Heroku. What I don't understand is why it is still working on localhost and not on Heroku. On the log it seems to work because "sw registered", "sw cached" and sometimes "update found, refresh the page to update" get logged on the console, you can try it by yourself. What you suggest doing?